# how to rewrite querystring string to name-space?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using .htacess and i need to rewrite querystring to name-space as the following:

```
general_page.php?code=2 To about-us 

general_page.php?code=4 To contact
```

Comment: This is very basic stuff. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is what you want

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about-us$ /general_page.php?code=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ /general_page.php?code=4 [L]
```

this will translate http://foo.com/about-us to http://foo.com/general_page.php?code=2 and http://foo.com/contact to http://foo.com/general_page.php?code=4

Comment: i want exactly this but not working give me an error 404.

Comment: sorry there was an extra /, try it now